# Unordered list not staying centered in DIV.

Tags: css, html, html-lists, responsive-design

While working on a responsive design, I noticed that everything is responsive except for my unordered list. When I resize the browser, the list doesn't move or stay centered in its DIV. I've tried a bunch of things all day but simply can't figure it out. For context, #sitecontent is the container holding everything, #sitecontent .leftsidebar contains an image and the unordered list, and #sitecontent .leftsidebar ul is the unordered list. Can someone check it out and tell me what's wrong? Please visit my site at http://www.tommaxwell.me and view the source.

Comment: everything's fine for me

Comment: What browser are you having issues on?

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS:

```
#sitecontent .leftsidebar ul {
position: relative;
top: -5px;
list-style-type: none;
font-family: 'Patua One', cursive;
padding-left: 10px;
}

#sitecontent .leftsidebar ul li {
margin-bottom: 3%;
clear: both;
border-bottom: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
font-family: helvetica;
text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My browser is adding some padding to the list, which is a pretty common thing for browsers to do. You might consider using a reset ([meyer](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/), [yui](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/cssreset/)), or just setting explicit padding/margin on the ul and li's.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I was overcomplicating the whole thing, and in the process forgetting the whole point of responsive designs in the first place. Adding padding/margin around the list is absolutely acceptable to use in the case, as I'll use media queries at breakpoints. Don't know why I was making things so complicated in my head!

Comment: You should consider accepting an answer if you found one particularly useful. It is also ok to accept your own answer if none of the given answers solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hi update your **css** with mine actually i have given the horizontal `padding` to your `.leftsidebar ul parent div` and made some changes in its `list-items` and its working fine now.. see the attached image for your reference :-

[image]

**CSS for till IPad**

```
#sitecontent .leftsidebar ul {
    padding: 0 25%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
}

#sitecontent .leftsidebar ul li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
    display: block;
    font-family: helvetica;
    line-height: 25px;
    margin: 2px;
}
```

And for `iphone` you will have to write the **css** :-

image reference for iphone :- [image]

**CSS for till IPhone**

```
#sitecontent .leftsidebar ul {
    margin-top: 10%;
    margin-bottom:20%;
    position: relative;
}
```